# What is the JQuery equivalent to document.forms["id"]["name"].value;

Tags: jquery

What's the jQuery equivalent syntax to `document.forms["id"]["name"].value;`?

I've tried :

```
let firstname = $("form #booking_form name").val(); // undefined
let name = $("form #booking_form firstname").val(); // undefined
```

I want to change this :

```
let firstname = document.forms["booking_form"]["name"].value;
let name = document.forms["booking_form"]["firstname"].value;

console.log(name); undefined
console.log(firstname); undefined
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: A question like this should include the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 2):

The `document.forms` collection is indexed by the `name` attribute of the `form`, and the same goes for the child form controls, so the jQuery equivalent of `document.forms["id"]["name"].value` is:

```
$('form[name="id"] :input[name="name"]').val();
```

To convert your first example would be:

```
let firstname = $('form[name="booking_form"] :input[name="name"]').val();
let name = $('form[name="booking_form"] :input[name="firstname"]').val();
```

As you can see this is a little cumbersome. You'd be better off putting classes or ids on the form controls to enable you to select them directly.

Comment: What does the `:` before input (`:input`) do, Rory?

Comment: @cale_b it's the [`:input` selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). It will match any `input`, `select`, `textarea` or `button` element - as the `document.forms[formName]` collection would.

Comment: `:input` ensures you have an input.  `<div name=myinput>` would not be included

Comment: @freedomn-m - understood, makes sense - but I'd also cringe at a `div` with a `name` attribute :)

Comment: @cale_b likewise :)

Comment: Right, that's better with ids :D Thanks Rory !!